# How to Sum and Mulitply row of Specific Column in SQl Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database with table **units** with column name **Transformertype** and **Transformeramount** and **section**.

I want to first multiply **Transformertype** and **Transformeramount** and then add them but only where Section column contain specific type of value like  'Pattika', 'Baheri' and 'Kahori'. and then display it into label.

My Query is

```sql
select
    SUM(TransformerType*TransformerAmount)
from
    units
where
    (Section LIKE'%Pattika%')
    And
    (Section LIKE '%Baheri%' )
    And
    (Section LIKE '%Kahori%')
```

But this query not showing any result into my label. Help Require

Comment: You need to use `OR`, not `AND`.

Comment: @Dai thats right, but also I think is not a typo, also confuses the SUM with +

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is an aggregate function. It will sum the total for each group.

I don't know if I understand 100% your query, but please comment here and I will glad to update my answer:

```
select
    SUM(TransformerType*TransformerAmount),
    section,
    COUNT(*) as TotalSection
from
    units
where
    (Section LIKE'%Pattika%')
    OR
    (Section LIKE '%Baheri%' )
    OR
    (Section LIKE '%Kahori%') 

GROUP BY Section
```